# Where can I get Raven.Storage.Esent.dll & Raven.Storage.Managed.dll

Tags: ravendb

I was going through one of the WPF article in which the author of that article has included the following Raven.Storage.Esent.dll & Raven.Storage.Managed.dll. When I downloaded the latest RavenDB bundle I couldn't find both the dlls. Can any one help me to get this dlls. Is it removed from the latest version ? If yes, then what is the equivalent of the same dlls.

Thanks
Dhana

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle that is by going to nuget and getting the [RavenDB.Embedded](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Embedded) package.

Comment: I downloaded RavenDB Embedded Package, but I couldnt find this particular dlls.